# Como hacer que se ejecute el método de un backbean al abrir la página

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, xhtml

Estoy de prácticas y estamos trabajando con JSF, Backbeans y estas tecnologías que para mi son semi-nuevas.

Trabajamos con una base de datos de contactos y lo que quiero hacer es que haya una página para buscar un contacto y que a la vez, muestre la lista de contactos, pero no se como hacer que al cargar la página (listar.xhtml) se muestren todos los contactos en su correspondiente tabla. Ahora mismo lo que tengo hecho es que le tengas que dar a un botón para que se carguen. Supongo que esto se hará en el XHTML, ya que el Bean ya está programado, por lo que dejo el código de la página.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Agenda - Contactos
    
    


    
        
        Agenda web Dinámica

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.xhtml">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="listar.xhtml" class="active">Contactos</a></li>
        <li><a href="modificar.xhtml">Modificar</a></li>
        <li><a href="agregar.xhtml">Agregar</a></li>
        <li><a href="delete.xhtml">Eliminar</a></li>
        <li><a href="tareas.xhtml">Tareas</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <!-- END - HEADER -->
    <h3>Contactos</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="nombre" value="Buscar" />
            <h:inputText id="nombre" value="#{contactoBean.nombre}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{contactoBean.buscar}" />
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Ver tus contactos"
            action="#{contactoBean.listar}" />
    </h:form>

    <table id="list">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Apodo</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="telefono"
                    value="#{contactoBean.nombre}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="telefono"
                    value="#{contactoBean.telefono}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="telefono" value="#{contactoBean.apodo}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="telefono"
                    value="#{contactoBean.ciudad}" /></td>
            <td><h:outputLabel for="telefono" value="#{contactoBean.email}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h:dataTable id="list" value="#{contactoBean.listaContactos}" var="c"
        class="lista">
        <h:column>
            #{c.nombre}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            #{c.telefono}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            #{c.apodo}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            #{c.ciudad}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            #{c.email}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    <h:messages />
</f:view>
```

Si precisáis del código fuente del Bean, pedírmelo y lo posteo, es para que no quede demasiado largo el hilo, gracias!

Comment: Utilizas JSF 2?

Comment: Si, JSF 2.2.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu backingbean, anota un método con `@PostConstruct`, solo puede haber uno, y se cargará cuando se instancie el backingBean.
Sería algo así:

```
public class ContactoBean{
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar(){
        listaContactos = cargarListaContactos();
    }
...
}
```